# EmberJS global keyPress

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Does ember have a way to allow ember components to capture/listen to global keypress events without having to set focus (as described by the attached links)?

Is there an elegant way of doing this in the latest version on Ember ?

[Global keyDown/keyPress events in EmberJS without having to set focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336308/global-keydown-keypress-events-in-emberjs-without-having-to-set-focus)

[Ember.js: View listening for keypress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346985/ember-js-view-listening-for-keypress-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI best way to implement this is to use the Mousetrap.js http://craig.is/killing/mice

Ember CLI instructions

1. bower install --save mousestrap
2. Add /* global Mousetrap */ to the top of the file you want to use mouse trap in (which in my case was a custom component
3. Example usage:

   ```
   didInsertElement: function() {
    Mousetrap.bind('right', function() {
         alert('right direction arrow clicked');
       });
   }
   ```